# How do I reset a multi-dimentional list after any action is made (Noob Java coding in Chess)?

Tags: java, chess, 2d-games

I'm learning to code Java by myself after learning a bit of the language and decided to make a non-graphical game of Chess.

The First Problem: 
Here is my multidimentional list of Strings which is in the "Board.java":

```
public static String chessBoard[][][] = {
        { { "A1" }, { "A2" }, { "A3" }, { "A4" }, { "A5" }, { "A6" },
                { "A7" }, { "A8" } },
        { { "B1" }, { "B2" }, { "B3" }, { "B4" }, { "B5" }, { "B6" },
                { "B7" }, { "B8" } },
        { { "C1" }, { "C2" }, { "C3" }, { "C4" }, { "C5" }, { "C6" },
                { "C7" }, { "C8" } },
        { { "D1" }, { "D2" }, { "D3" }, { "D4" }, { "D5" }, { "D6" },
                { "D7" }, { "D8" } },
        { { "E1" }, { "E2" }, { "E3" }, { "E4" }, { "E5" }, { "E6" },
                { "E7" }, { "E8" } },
        { { "F1" }, { "F2" }, { "F3" }, { "F4" }, { "F5" }, { "F6" },
                { "F7" }, { "F8" } },
        { { "G1" }, { "G2" }, { "G3" }, { "G4" }, { "G5" }, { "G6" },
                { "G7" }, { "G8" } },
        { { "H1" }, { "H2" }, { "H3" }, { "H4" }, { "H5" }, { "H6" },
                { "H7" }, { "H8" } }, };
```

If I place a pawn (from "WPawn.java") on the board I get:

```
    A1  A2  A3  A4  A5  A6  A7  A8  
    WP1 B2  B3  B4  B5  B6  B7  B8  
    C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6  C7  C8  
    D1  D2  D3  D4  D5  D6  D7  D8  
    E1  E2  E3  E4  E5  E6  E7  E8  
    F1  F2  F3  F4  F5  F6  F7  F8  
    G1  G2  G3  G4  G5  G6  G7  G8  
    H1  H2  H3  H4  H5  H6  H7  H8
```

I want the resulting list (above) to return to the original list (from the first code), but how do I do that?

Thanks in advance :)

```
public static void update() {
    // Print chessBoard nicely
    System.out.println("Here is the board: ");
    for (int row = 0; row < chessBoard.length; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < chessBoard[row].length; column++) {
            for (int pos = 0; pos < chessBoard[row][column].length; pos++) {
                System.out.print(chessBoard[row][column][pos] + "\t");
            }

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    // end
}
```

Comment: Why is your array 3-dimensional? Wouldn't `{ { { "A1" }, { "A2" }, { "A3" }, { "A4" }, { "A5" }, { "A6" }, { "A7" }, { "A8" } },...` be simpler as `{ { "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8" },...`?

Comment: its because I had thought too keep a history of all moves made in each position, but yes, I should change that out now :P

Comment: Do you actually want hints concerning programming style and data structure, or is it a very specific question, @INear?

Comment: You really really should not have a 3D array for this. A 2D array represents the grid. Any information could be linked to a specific element on the grid using a Map. (In this case, maybe `Map<String, DataYouWant> map = new HashMap<String, DataYouWant>();` would work fine)

Comment: @Matmarbon it was more like a specific question, but I'm open to any advice on how I could improve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not questioning your current data structure, I guess you just need to do something like this

```
public class Chess {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][][] chessBoard = initBoard();
        //do what you want
        //...
        //reset
        chessBoard = initBoard();
    }

    private static String[][][] initBoard() {
        return new String[][][]{
            { { "A1" }, { "A2" }, { "A3" }, { "A4" }, { "A5" }, { "A6" }, { "A7" }, { "A8" } },
            { { "B1" }, { "B2" }, { "B3" }, { "B4" }, { "B5" }, { "B6" }, { "B7" }, { "B8" } },
            { { "C1" }, { "C2" }, { "C3" }, { "C4" }, { "C5" }, { "C6" }, { "C7" }, { "C8" } },
            { { "D1" }, { "D2" }, { "D3" }, { "D4" }, { "D5" }, { "D6" }, { "D7" }, { "D8" } },
            { { "E1" }, { "E2" }, { "E3" }, { "E4" }, { "E5" }, { "E6" }, { "E7" }, { "E8" } },
            { { "F1" }, { "F2" }, { "F3" }, { "F4" }, { "F5" }, { "F6" }, { "F7" }, { "F8" } },
            { { "G1" }, { "G2" }, { "G3" }, { "G4" }, { "G5" }, { "G6" }, { "G7" }, { "G8" } },
            { { "H1" }, { "H2" }, { "H3" }, { "H4" }, { "H5" }, { "H6" }, { "H7" }, { "H8" } }, };
    }

}
```

Comment: This is what I think I'm looking for. Thank you!
but I have another question....
What if I was using the "chessBoard" as a global variable before (apparently its a local variable now)?

Comment: @INear Does not matter. You can assign the result of initBoard() to whatever variable you want.

Comment: you're changing your question on the fly

Comment: Am I? Sorry.
I thought 'extensions' might have been alright :(

Answer (score 0):

I usually prefer to save space in memory, so when I want to restore the array, I would just use the following method:

```
public static void fill(String[][] grid) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
            grid[y][x] = (char) (65 + y) + "" + (x + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

65 is the ASCII value for the upper-case A, in case you didn't know. The method will increment the letter along with the number as well.

Also note that the method uses a *2D* array, not a *3D* array, so it will *not* work with the array you provided.